# White screen on touchscreen display

Tags: hardware, display, driver

I connected my [3.5" touchscreen display](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-5-inch-IPS-touchscreen-LCD-For-Pi2-B-Ubuntu-Raspbian/32312221245.html) to the raspberry and nothing appears on it.

When I start the raspberry, only the white screen appears and doesn't disappear.

However, connecting an external monitor (via hdmi) works fine.

What is the problem? Maybe some drivers missing? Is it possible to install them? Is this a known problem?

I'm running NOOBS 1.4.1

Maybe should I try [their distribution](http://www.spotpear.com/download/image/)?

Comment: Can you give us display link ?

Comment: @dastaan I edited my question. Some stuff is [here](http://www.spotpear.com/download/image/).

Comment: Most - if not all - displays don't work out of the box.  Almost sure it's because a driver problem - or better a lack of driver.  It won't hurt to download their image and give it a try.  It's easy to copy the image to your card and you'll find out directly whether your display is actually a working one or a broken one.

Comment: @EDP And is there a general solution for these problems?

Comment: I've edited my comment above.

Comment: @EDP Their `7zip` archive is corrupted... Can you try to [unzip it](http://www.spotpear.com/download/image/RPi-3.5inch-LCD-150602.7z) and send me the img file?

Comment: You should definitely consider their distribution since It comes with prebuilt drivers.

Comment: Stay away from NOOBS, go for Raspbian and as @dastaan said, go for their distribution.  I'll try to download if you're telling me which Pi model you have.

Comment: @EDP I have a [Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/In-stock-MADE-IN-UK-2015-New-Original-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-Broadcom-BCM2836-1G/32364336740.html). Works fine with external monitor, but not with this screen. I downloaded their archive from [here](http://www.spotpear.com/download/image/RPi-3.5inch-LCD-150602.7z), but when I try to extract the img file, I get [an error](http://i.imgur.com/gI7TFKL.png).

Comment: Try using this wiki. It has good instructions and helps you install drivers for the tft display: http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display#Driver_Installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, it was a problem with the drivers. I switched to use [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) and then I installed the drivers, like explained [here](http://www.spotpear.com/learn/EN/raspberry-pi/Raspberry-Pi-LCD/Drive-the-LCD.html).

- Dowloaded [the driver](http://www.spotpear.com/download/diver24-5/LCD-show-150602.tar.gz)
- Extracted the files (`tar xvf LCD-show.tar.gz`)
- `cd LCD-show/`
- `sudo ./LCD35-show` (this depends on the display size, mine is 3.5")

In my case it didn't reboot automatically, but it displayed some messages regarding that. I unplugged the pi and force-restarted.

Comment: I was facing the same problem but with the addition that I had to put the LCD-show directory right into the home of the user pi ~/LCD-show.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, **i bought a similar item** (linked below) but **couldn't find matching drivers** for the lcd *([@Ionică Bizău's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34290/27170) didn't worked for me)*

I contact the seller and he replied with **[this url](http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html)** included with download links for complete image bundled with drivers:

[image]

---

FYI this is the product i bought from ebay:
**[3-5-TFT-Raspberry-Pi-2-B-B-Touch-Screen-Display-Monitor-LCD-Case-Heatsink](http://www.ebay.com/itm/271818699326)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I did it with the drivers and the advice on their Ebay site. You have to modify some parameters if you use more actual drivers (e.g. LCD_show -> LCD_show_v6_1_2 or LCD35_v1 -> LCD35_v).

Installation:

- Get drivers: `wget http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_2.tar.gz`
- Decompress file: `tar -xzvf LCD_show_v6_1_2.tar.gz`
- Jump into the file: `cd LCD-show`
- Update system: `sudo apt-get update`
- Install driver: `sudo ./LCD35_v1`

Then, after a few seconds, the system will reboot (just WAIT!)

If you want to use the HDMI, you can use the command: `sudo ./LCD_hdmi`

Note: You must use the command `sudo apt-mark hold raspberrypi-bootloader`  before you update your system.

Then use the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```